# ImageMagick or another approach: How to find the coordinates of the centre of an object in an image?

Tags: image, imagemagick, coordinates

I am trying to find the coordinates of the object in the image (mug). [image]

What I need to derive in the end in terms of information is x, y, width and height - where x and y should be the centre of the rectangle encompassing the mug (and not the top-left corner) and width and height should be float values relative to width and height of image (from 0.0 to 1.0).

I tried installing ImageMagick, loading the image, and then running the below command in cmd:

```
magick image1.jpg -define connected-components:verbose=true -connected-components 8 -auto-level image1.jpg
```

I get the error: **magick: too many objects `image1.jpg' @ error/vision.c/ConnectedComponentsImage/437.**

Does anyone know how to fix that, or any other relatively straightforward approach to find the required coordinates?

Comment: In order to use connected component, you need to some how segment your mug object (foreground) from the background and make a binary image. Unfortunately, your object is the same color as the background. So it is very hard to do that by simple image processing. You would need an AI/Deep learning approach such as at http://remove.bg  If you can use that to separate your foreground from the background, then -connected-components can tell you what you want. But how can width and height of the mug be in range 0 to 1. Is that a fraction relative to the size of the input?

Comment: I am guessing so. In fact, I am following the instructions on https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/tree/47c7af1cea5bbdedf1184963355e6418cb8b1b4f#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects to train my custom object using YOLO version 2. More specifically, those ones: "Create .txt-file for each .jpg-image-file - in the same directory and with the same name, but with .txt-extension, and put to file: object number and object coordinates on this image, for each object in new line: <object-class> <x> <y> <width> <height>"

Comment: See my answer below with example of connected components after removing the background.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, your object is the same color as the background. So it is very hard to do that by simple image processing. You would need an AI/Deep learning approach such as at http://remove.bg

So I have used http://remove.bg to do that, but note that remove.bg has shrunk the image a bit.

[image]

From that I extract the alpha channel:

```
convert mug.png -alpha extract mug_alpha.png
```

[image]

```
WxH=`convert mug_alpha.png -format "%wx%h" info:`
W=`echo $WxH | cut -dx -f1`
H=`echo $WxH | cut -dx -f2`

bbox=`convert mug_alpha.png \
-type bilevel \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:exclude-header=true \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:keep-top=1 \
-connected-components 4 \
null: | grep "gray(255)" | awk '{print $2}' | tr "x" "+"`
wd=`echo $bbox | cut -d+ -f1`
ht=`echo $bbox | cut -d+ -f2`
xoff=`echo $bbox | cut -d+ -f3`
yoff=`echo $bbox | cut -d+ -f4`

xcenter=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$xoff + $wd/2]" info:`
ycenter=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$yoff + $ht/2]" info:`
width=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$wd/$W]" info:`
height=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$ht/$H]" info:`
echo "xcenter=$xcenter, ycenter=$ycenter, width=$width, height=$height"
```

**xcenter=277, ycenter=260, width=0.563433, height=0.60515**

```
left=$xoff
top=$yoff
right=$((xoff+wd-1))
bottom=$((yoff+ht-1))
convert mug.png -fill none -stroke red -draw "rectangle $left,$top $right,$bottom" -alpha off mug_box.png
convert mug_alpha.png -fill none -stroke red -draw "rectangle $left,$top $right,$bottom" -alpha off mug_alpha_box.png
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just a clarifying question, do you run the code in cmd?

Comment: This is run in command line mode. The syntax is Unix (Linux, Max OSX, Windows 10 Unix). Windows DOS scripting would be different.

Comment: Thank you very much. I myself am using Windows DOS, but will try and search for a similar script. Thanks again!